# Обработчик ответа сервера вне класса

Tags: javascript

Есть класс `Search` который обращается к серверу и возвращает результат. Обращение к серверу висит на событии `input`. Как можно обработать конкретный ответ (например xxx) вне класса `Search`.
Из идей это повесить промис на свойство `result`, но ожидаемо выполниться один раз, а нужно что бы при каждом совпадении.
Можно ли сделать это как то иначе?

Что бы быть уверенным, в том что обработан именно последний запрос использую `this.query_id != query_id`, но не нравиться что это используется в трех местах. Как можно исправить?

Хотел использовать `AbortController`, но он отменяет выполнение всех подписанных на него.

**UPD:**
Можно передавать обработчик в метод `init(fn)` или свойство `result` сделать объектом и обернуть его в прокси, что будет правильнее?

```js
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  text += Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 10000)) + 10000;
  return text;
}


class Search {
  search_field = document.getElementById('search');
  search_mirror = document.getElementById('mirror');
  query_id;
  result;

  constructor() { }

  init() {
    this.result = new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.search_field.oninput = this.runSearch.bind(this, resolve);
    });
  }

  runSearch(resolve) {
    if (this.search_field.value.length < 0) return false;
    const url = `https://httpbin.org/post`;
    const query_id = makeid();

    this.query_id = query_id;

    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: this.search_field.value
      })
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("ERR-167: Ошибка соединения с сервером!");
      }
    }).then(
      (result) => {
        if (this.query_id != query_id) return true;
        let res = result.json.message;
        this.search_mirror.innerText = res;
        if (res == 'xxx') resolve(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        if (this.query_id != query_id) return true;
        console.error(err);
      }
    ).finally(() => {
      if (this.query_id != query_id) return true;
      console.log('done');
    });

  }
}

let search = new Search();
search.init();

search.result.then(
  res => {
    alert('goal');
    console.log(res);
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="search" placeholder="xxx">
<div id="mirror"></div>
```

Comment: Уточните что Вы хотите сделать. Что значит "конкретный ответ"? Вот выполняете запрос на сервер, он отправляет Вам ответ. Что дальше?

Comment: @Gelloiss в данном примере, "конкретный ответ" значит строка 'xxx', а дальше эта строка может быть куда нибудь вставлена, но этим не должен заниматься класс `Search`. На рабочем примере вместо строки 'xxx' будет объект с результатами поиска,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UPD: Можно передавать обработчик в метод init(fn) или свойство result сделать объектом и обернуть его в прокси, что будет правильнее?

Не уверен насчет правильности данного решения, тк. ответ обрабатывается все равно в классе `Search`, но обработчик можно задать из вне

```js
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  text += Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 10000)) + 10000;
  return text;
}


class Search {
  search_field = document.getElementById('search');
  search_mirror = document.getElementById('mirror');
  query_id;
  result = {
    data: {},
    handler: false
  };

  constructor() {
    this.result = new Proxy(this.result, {
      set(target, prop, val, receiver) {
        if (prop == 'data' && target.handler instanceof Function) target.handler(val);
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, val, receiver);
      },
    });
  }

  init() {
    this.search_field.oninput = this.runSearch.bind(this);
  }

  runSearch(resolve) {
    if (this.search_field.value.length < 0) return false;
    const url = `https://httpbin.org/post`;
    const query_id = makeid();

    this.query_id = query_id;

    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: this.search_field.value
      })
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("ERR-167: Ошибка соединения с сервером!");
      }
    }).then(
      (result) => {
        if (this.query_id != query_id) return true;
        let res = result.json.message;
        this.search_mirror.innerText = res;
        if (res == 'xxx') this.result.data = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        if (this.query_id != query_id) return true;
        console.error(err);
      }
    ).finally(() => {
      if (this.query_id != query_id) return true;
      console.log('done');
    });

  }
}

let search = new Search();
search.init();

search.result.handler = result => {
  alert('goal');
  console.log(result);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="search" placeholder="xxx">
<div id="mirror"></div>
```